# How to detect where CPU load is coming from in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I've created a few light monitoring scripts for a server I've set up.

One of the scripts tests for sustained high CPU load, and has been sending notices once a day in the middle of the night. But the alerts have been sent at different times each nigh, so the CPU load doesn't seem to be related to any of the regular cron jobs I have set up.

I know I can use `top` to view CPU usage breakdown in realtime, but is there any tool I can use in a bash script that would report what apps are using the most CPU % at a given moment in time?

Comment: Did you try `ps -rf`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks for the suggestion. That only seems to list processes for the active TTY though, and doesn't list processes being run by other users or background processes. Eg, if I look in top there are usually dozens of processes running, but ps -rf only shows one process (itself). It won't tell me if a background process is chewing up the CPU, or if someone has somehow managed to compromise the server to run processes from another system account.

Comment: `man ps` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ps -eo pid,cmd,%cpu --sort=-%cpu | head
```

This reports:

- `pid`: process id
- `cmd`: command
- `%cpu`: percentage of cpu used
- `--sort=-%cpu`: sort by decreasing cpu usage
- `| head`: show only the top 10 lines of the output, adjust as required.

You can set this command in crontab, have it run every minute and output it a log file.  It will give you an idea of what is going on at night.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I've also added 'user' to the list of columns to report, so this should now also report which system account the given processes are running under. Thanks again